# Print doesnt print out the content i assigned in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i'm a beginner in programming. I have a question about `dictionary`, I have done some research but still doesn't fix the problem. I created a dictionary using integral 0, 1, 2 and 3 as key and `(words)` as content. I tried using `get()` function to retrieve the key in the dictionary and trying to print out the content in a if statement, but it prints out None. Below is the coding (not full but I take those related parts):

This is the dictionary:

```
class Fact(object):
    facts = {
        0 : "I heard something... someone saying...\nI... I... oh yes! The killer is a guy!.",
        1 : "2",
        2 : "3"
}
```

And this is how I code.

```
class People(object):

    def __init__(self, vital, mental, evidance_count):
        self.vital = vital
        self.mental = mental
        self.evidance_count = evidance_count

    def evidance(self, locate):
        return Fact.facts.get(locate)

    def talk(self):
        talk = self.evidance(self.evidance_count)
        self.evidance_count += 1
```

I also created a class Andy which inherits the class People, removed the unrelated part:

```
class Andy(People):

    def play(self):
    if self.mental < 6: #i only coded some basic print and raw_input before this part to reach my desired self.mental value = 4 which is less than 6.
        print self.talk()
    else:
        print "You did't get any hint from Andy."

    return Andy(self.vital, self.mental, self.evidance_count)
```

This is the end part of my code to initiate the codes:

```
hint = 0
andy = Andy(1, 5, hint)
andy.play()

print andy.vital
print andy.mental
print andy.evidance_count
```

I didn't get an error. But this:

```
None
1
4
1
```

I was expecting to get this, :

```
I heard something... someone saying...\nI... I... oh yes! The killer is a guy!.
1
4
1
```

Does anyone know which part of my code has gone wrong??

Comment: `talk` doesn't `return` or `print` what it gets from `evidance`.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you NEED to use a dictionary? Because a list is more appropriate for matching integers to some strings. Like `a=['foo','bar','baz']` and accessing via `a[0]`

Comment: @Dschoni At first when I tried to design the code I wanted to use list but it doesn't print out so after some time I changed and tried using dictionary.

Comment: `print(a[0])` in my case will happily print 'foo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `talk` function needs to return the value:

```
def talk(self):
    talk = self.evidance(self.evidance_count)
    self.evidance_count += 1
    return talk
```

Produces output:

```
I heard something... someone saying...
I... I... oh yes! The killer is a guy!.
1
5
1
```